# Gitlab output log display runtime values instead of variables

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Is it possible to get GitLab to report out what it's actually running in the output log.  For example, the following .gitlab-ci.yml

```
variables:
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: >-
    -s $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/settings.xml
    --batch-mode
    --errors
    --fail-at-end
    --show-version
    -DinstallAtEnd=true
    -DdeployAtEnd=true

compile-test-package:
  stage: package
  script:
    - mvn ${MAVEN_CLI_OPTS} package
```

The run log then shows this

```
...
mvn ${MAVEN_CLI_OPTS} package
...
```

But I really would like it to give the specific details like

```
...
mvn -s path/to/my/project/.m2/settings.xml --batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version -DinstallAtEnd=true -DdeployAtEnd=true package
...
```

Comment: You could always echo the line and then execute it. It’s gross but yeah I don’t think there’s a way to do this

Comment: Thanks...I had thought of that but seems very redundant but if there is no other option to enable this guess its all I can do.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The best I've learned on this is that GitLab doesn't have a way to report the full details of what its executing.  As Michael Delgado mentioned, putting an echo in to output will give you a method to do this.   However use this with caution cause protected values could be exposed using this method.

I'm still struggling with variable replacement but at least now I can see what GitLab is replacing and is not.